# Hot to get the attribute from .getElementsByTagName?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Do not undertand why I can not get the **attribute value** of tag element by using function `getElementsByTagName`.

Also I have no problems with using direct acsess to the element by `id` , like `t.getAttribute('href')` from `<a id="t">.</a>`

```js
 var a = document.body.getElementsByTagName('a').getAttribute('href');
    console.log(a);
```

```html
 <a href="###">http://internal.com/</a>
```

Comment: `var a = document.body.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('href');` or `var a = document.body.querySelector('a').getAttribute('href');` Note the plural **"elements"** in the method name. See the linked question's answers for details. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` will return a array so put the index and get the element you want

```js
 var a = document.body.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('href');
    console.log(a);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="###">http://internal.com/</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I had simplified this code. i need it work to an array of **a** tags.
The loop is not working ((
`var a = document.body.getElementsByTagName('a');

 for (var i = 0; i , a.length; i++) {
  a[i].getAttribute('href');
 }`

Comment: will update the answer